# Start/Update variable scoping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scope

I have a SceneController that's supposed to initialize a set of empty GameObject spawners, each working together at the same rhythm. The RockSpawners receive an array of time delays and wait the X seconds between spawning another rock.

I set the `_nextSpawn = float.maxValue` when the spawners start and plan to overwrite this after "Initializing" them (my own method), however even though my debug logs say I've overwritten my `_nextSpawn` value while initializing, the update loop is still reporting `float.maxValue` and nothing ends up spawning because `_timeSinceLastSpawn` hasn't exceeded `float.maxValue` seconds.

Is there something I'm missing with the scope of my `_nextSpawn` variables? It doesn't seem to be a "this" vs "local" issue, at least at first glance.

Debug output: `0 0 3 3`. 0's stay the same, 3's will vary based on rng.

SceneController.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SceneController : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _rockSpawnerPrefab;

    public int numRocks = 6;
    public int minSpawnDelaySec = 1;
    public int maxSpawnDelaySec = 3;
    private bool spawnersInitialized = false;

    void Start () {
        InitializeSpawners();
    }

    void Update () {
    }

    void InitializeSpawners() {
        float[] pattern = new float[numRocks];

        for (int i = 0; i < numRocks; i++) {
            // Generate delays at half second increments within bounds
            float delay = Mathf.Floor(Random.value * ((float)(maxSpawnDelaySec + 0.5f - minSpawnDelaySec) / 0.5f));
            delay = delay * 0.5f + minSpawnDelaySec;
            pattern[i] = delay;
        }

        GameObject spawner = Instantiate(_rockSpawnerPrefab) as GameObject;
        spawner.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 4, 0);
        RockSpawner rockSpawnerScript = spawner.GetComponent<RockSpawner>();
        rockSpawnerScript.Initialize(pattern);
    }
}
```

RockSpawner.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RockSpawner : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _rockPrefab;

    public float minSpawnDelay = 3f;
    public float maxSpawnDelay = 6f;
    private float[] _pattern;
    private int _currentPattern;
    private float _timeSinceLastSpawn;
    private float _nextSpawn;

    void Start () {
        _currentPattern = -1;
        _nextSpawn = float.MaxValue;
    }

    void Update () {
        if (_pattern == null) return;

        _timeSinceLastSpawn += Time.deltaTime;

        if (_timeSinceLastSpawn > _nextSpawn) {
            GameObject rock = Instantiate(_rockPrefab) as GameObject;
            rock.transform.position = transform.position;

            NextTimer();
        }
    }

    public void Initialize(float[] pattern) {
        _pattern = pattern;
        NextTimer();
    }

    private void NextTimer() {
        _timeSinceLastSpawn = 0;
        _currentPattern += 1;
        Debug.Log(_nextSpawn);
        Debug.Log(this._nextSpawn);
        this._nextSpawn = _pattern[_currentPattern];
        Debug.Log(_nextSpawn);
        Debug.Log(this._nextSpawn);
    }

}
```

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, good catch. It looks like Initialize() is called before Start(). Strange. I guess `RockSpawner.Start()` may not be getting invoked until `SceneController.Start()` completes, implying all object Start()'s may run serially.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about scoping, it's about call order. When you create a `GameObject` its [`Start` method is called on the frame it's enabled](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html), not when the object is created. So your code will call `Initialize` *first*, then `Start` which overwrites the values.

Remove the code in `Start` and handle everything in `Initialize` and it should work as you want.

Comment: Thanks Sami. Debug logs confirmed Initialize was called before Start. Removing the start logic and setting _currentPattern = -1 at the top fixed the issue. Appreciate the help!